# Tweetbot URL Scheme not opening user

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I've been trying to get Tweetbot to open a user account when a table row is tapped by the user. However, although Tweetbot opens, it doesn't show the user account. I've been using the Tweetbot URL Scheme page as a reference.

Below is my code:

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        // Removed the actual username
        self.destViewURL = @"http://twitter.com/dummyusername";
        self.destViewTitle = @"Twitter";
        
        // URLs to try
        NSURL *twitterURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name= dummyusername"];
        NSURL *tweetbotURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tweetbot://dummyusername/timeline"];

        // Check if Tweetbot is available to open it
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:tweetbotURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:tweetbotURL];
        }
        
        else {
            // Check if Twitter is available to open it
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:twitterURL]) {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:twitterURL];
            }
            
            // Otherwise open it in the web view
            else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showWebView" sender:nil];
            }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The URL schemes page for Tweetbot 3 is [here](http://tapbots.net/tweetbot3/support/url-schemes/)

All of the supported URLs begin with `tweetbot://<screenname>`, which suggests that you need to know the user's existing twitter screen name to link to a profile.

However, my testing has shown that you could link directly to a profile by using the same value for `tweetbot://<screenname>/user_profile/<profile_screenname>`

Swift e.g.

```
   /* Tweetbot app precedence */
   if let tweetbotURL = NSURL(string: "tweetbot://dummyusername/user_profile/dummyusername") {
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(tweetbotURL) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(tweetbotURL)
            return
        }
    }

    /* Twitter app fallback */
    if let twitterURL = NSURL(string: "twitter:///user?screen_name= dummyusername") {
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(twitterURL) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(twitterURL)
            return
        }
    }

    /* Safari fallback */
    if let webURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.twitter.com/dummyusername") {
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(webURL) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(webURL)
        }
    }
```